# Reading line per line, and evaluating strings into coordinates using fgets() and sscanf()

Tags: c, file-io, scanf, point-in-polygon

I'm trying to read multiple lines of vertices with varying length using fgets and sscanf.

```
(1,6),(2,6),(2,9),(1,9)
(1,5)
```

My program goes into an infinite loop stuck within the first vertex.

```
    char temp3[255];
    while(fgets(temp3, 255, fp)!= NULL){
        printf("Polygon %d: ", polycount);
        while(sscanf(temp3, "(%d,%d)", &polygonx[polycount][vertcount], &polygony[polycount][vertcount]) != EOF){
            sscanf(temp3, ",");
            printf("(%d,%d),",polygonx[polycount][vertcount], polygony[polycount][vertcount]);
            vertcount++;
        }
        vertcounts[polycount] = vertcount;
        vertcount = 0;
        polycount++;
    }
```

I must be able to feed the x and y values of the vertices into the polygon arrays, so i'm stuck with using sscanf. I'm also having a problem since I cant find anything on the internet that scans varying numbers of elements per line.

Comment: `sscanf` reads the same thing over and over again causing an infinite loop. It doesn't advance as you think.

Comment: Fixed sscanf earlier, along with @iharob's suggestions. My main problem was with my pointer not being updated after an iteration of fgets(). Thanks, anyway. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because this

```
while(sscanf(temp3, "(%d,%d)", 
  &polygonx[polycount][vertcount], &polygony[polycount][vertcount]) != EOF)
 {
 }
```

is never going to be `true` I think, because `scanf()` returns the number of parameters succesfuly scanned, I would do this instead

```
while(sscanf(temp3, "(%d,%d)", 
  &polygonx[polycount][vertcount], &polygony[polycount][vertcount]) == 2)
 {
 }
```

Your code doesn't work because it does not satisfy the condition for `sscanf()` to return `EOF`, the following is from the manual page referenced at the end

> The value `EOF` is returned if the end of input is reached before either the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. `EOF` is also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator for the stream (see `ferror(3)`) is set, and errno is set to indicate the error.

So it appears that you are not reaching the end if input before the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs, which makes sense according to the contents of the file. And the second part applies only to file streams of course.

And instead of the `sscanf(temp3, ",")` which doesn't do what you think, you could do it like this

```
next = strchr(temp3, ',');
if (next != NULL)
    temp3 = next + 1;
else
    /* you've reached the end here */
```

This is a suggestion on how to parse this file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
    const char temp3[] = "(1,6),(2,6),(2,9),(1,9)\n(1,5)";
    char *source;
    int x, y;
    int count;
    source = temp3;
    while (sscanf(source, "(%d,%d)%*[^(]%n", &x, &y, &count) == 2)
    {
        /* this is just for code clarity */
        polygonx[polycount][vertcount] = x;
        polygony[polycount][vertcount] = y;
        /* Process here if needed, and then advance the pointer */
        source += count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `"%n"` specifier captures the number of characters scanned so far, so you can use it to advance the pointer to the las position scanned in the source string.

And the `"%*[^("` will skip all characters until the next `'('` is found.

Please refer to [`sscanf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) for more information on the `"%n"` specifier, and the `%[` specifier.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm using char temp3[255], so i think that's why your solution still doesnt work for me.

Comment: @bhounter You can easily make a pointer to an array, it's a natural thing in the c language, si my edit please.

Comment: Program is still going into an infinite loop. I presume it's not working well with fgets().

Comment: Take note that i have an unknown number of lines and vertices, so the above suggestion, with all strings in temp3, isnt my case.

Comment: @bhounter  So should spcify what exactly it is .

Answer (score 2):

If successfully read `sscanf` will return `2` in this case . `sscanf` returns numbers of variables filled.

Check if it returns `2` which will indicate success here .

```
while(sscanf(temp3,"(%d,%d)",&polygonx[polycount][vertcount],&polygony[polycount]][vertcount]) != EOF)
```

Instead of this , check like this -

```
 while(sscanf(temp3,"(%d,%d)%*c",&polygonx[polycount][vertcount],&polygony[polycount]][vertcount])== 2)
                             ^ to exclude the comma after it
```

also to ignore `','`  after the coordinates , you use -

```
sscanf(temp3, ",");
```

is not correct . In the above `sscanf` you can read it and discard it as well by using `%*c` specifier.

Comment: `"%*c"` is ok if there is just one `,` or any other character after the end of the tuple, `"%*[^(]"` would be more robust.

Comment: I don't think `%*c` does anything useful here. The `sscanf` would behave the same way if it wasn't there.

Comment: @iharob  I guess the format of code is fixed . And `(` will be matched in next iteratation . So we don't have to worry about that .

Comment: @CoolGuy  Nope , you were correct. I did really something dumb. Did really a blunder . :|

Comment: The solution in your answer won't work. `sscanf` doesn't advance on reading. Once the `sscanf` in your answer returns 2, you'll get an infinite loop.